How to UNPIVOT into multiple columns using unpivot or union all?
I have a table like this.
Name    Status 1    Action 1    Status 2    Action 2    Status 3    Action 3
AAA    Started     S            Pended          P           Closed          C
BBB   Started      S            Pended          P           Closed          C
CCC   Started      S            Closed          C

I need the output like below, it has seq no generator in output.
Name    Status   Action Seq No
AAA    Started   S      1
AAA    Pended    P      2
AAA    Closed    C      3
BBB    Started   S      1
BBB    Pended    P      2
BBB    Closed    C      3
CCC    Started   S      1
CCC    Closed    C      2

Not able to do this using unpivot.

Can you edit and fix proper columns?

Please add your best attempt. You write "Not able to do this using unpivot", so what have you tried?

you are using Oracle? Depending on the DBMS, you can have different functions that may help, but universally, union will do the thing.

Union is quite simple. For sample data:
SQL> WITH
  2     test (name,
  3           status_1,
  4           action_1,
  5           status_2,
  6           action_2,
  7           status_3,
  8           action_3)
  9     AS
 10        (SELECT 'AAA', 'Started', 'S', 'Pended', 'P', 'Closed', 'C' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'BBB', 'Started', 'S', 'Pended', 'P', 'Closed', 'C' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 'CCC', 'Started', 'S', 'Closed', 'C', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL)

query begins here:
 15  SELECT name,
 16         status_1 AS status,
 17         action_1 AS action,
 18         1  seq_no
 19    FROM test
 20   WHERE status_1 IS NOT NULL
 21  UNION ALL
 22  SELECT name,
 23         status_2,
 24         action_2,
 25         2  seq_no
 26    FROM test
 27   WHERE status_2 IS NOT NULL
 28  UNION ALL
 29  SELECT name,
 30         status_3,
 31         action_3,
 32         3  seq_no
 33    FROM test
 34   WHERE status_3 IS NOT NULL
 35  ORDER BY name, seq_no;

NAME STATUS  ACTION         SEQ_NO
---- ------- ---------- ----------
AAA  Started S                   1
AAA  Pended  P                   2
AAA  Closed  C                   3
BBB  Started S                   1
BBB  Pended  P                   2
BBB  Closed  C                   3
CCC  Started S                   1
CCC  Closed  C                   2

8 rows selected.

SQL>


UNION is indeed quite simple but also implies several scans of the table
select * from (
    select d.name,
        case s.seq
        when 1 then Status_1
        when 2 then Status_2
        else status_3
        end as status,
        case s.seq
        when 1 then Action_1
        when 2 then Action_2
        else Action_3
        end as action
        , s.seq
    from source_t d,
    (select level as seq from dual connect by level <= 3) s
)
where status is not null and action is not null
order by name, seq
;

and UNPIVOT is just
select * from source_t
unpivot (
    (status, action) for seq in (
        (status_1, action_1) as 1,
        (status_2, action_2) as 2,
        (status_3, action_3) as 3
    )
)

